# Workspace apps does not always appear for gmail IOS

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

It is not clear why sometimes it appears and sometimes it doesn’t.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you the developer of this add-on? It's hard to tell or unclear with your current info, but [this bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239371587) may be related.

Comment: Hi Daniel - yes I am the developer of this add on. I don't believe it's related to the actual add-on given that it sometimes is shown, sometimes it is not. It differs versus this bug report in the sense that it's all or nothing. When I see it, I see all 3 add-ons. When I don't, I see nothing. Is issuetracker.google.com a good place to repost this issue?